# blog post displaying within older post - loop issue?

Tags: posts, loop

I've got an interesting issue with my [blog page](http://zoparealty.com/blog/)-

Currently, I have two test posts- "Test Blog Post" and "Test Blog Post Deux."
Test Blog Post displayed as it should, however when I added the second post(Test Blog Post Deux), the post content seemed to have overwritten the older content.
You can see this in the post- the first paragraph begins with "This is another test blog post. Here’s some more ipsum.." and the second "This is a test blog post. Here’s some ipsum." without any post title, date, etc. in between.

Any ideas what's going on/how to fix?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="blog-meta">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <h3>posted by ZOPA on <?php the_time('m/d/Y \a\t g:i A') ?> | <?php the_tags('tags: ',' , ','<br />'); ?></h3>
</div><!-- end blog-meta -->
<div class="blog-post">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>  
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
            <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>  
        <?php endwhile; ?>  
        <?php else : ?>  
        //Something that happens when a post isn’t found.  
        <?php endif; ?>  

</div><!-- end blog-post -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_title()` section is outside the loop which starts with `if (have_posts())`

**consider reviewing:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development